# How to prevent Windows Mail (HxTsr.exe) from downloading attachments?

Tags: windows, email, windows-11

I have connected the official Windows Mail app to my Gmail account. While retrieving the emails, it also downloads the attachments.

For some reason, I am getting a lot of spam emails with shady attachments these days. So every time an attachment gets downloaded, my anti-virus starts beeping, which is super annoying and happening every day.

How do I prevent attachment from auto-downloading?

I tried unchecking `Always download full message and internet images` checkbox but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Filter the spam out before using Windows Mail. That will work. Use Outlook instead. That moves spam to Junk and does not download automatically.